# Given a date in integer format, how to convert it into a Date object?

Tags: datetime, jodatime

For an application, I nee to extract out a number of fields from a file upload.  One of these fields is a decimal date with no separators and as yyyyMMDD.  For example, today's date would be represented as 20130406.

Is there an existing utility in the Java Date classes or in Joda time that will convert this to a SQL-style DateTime field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly simple in JODA or basic Java date parsing, just convert to a string and use a parse pattern of YYYYMMdd.  The below works for JODA-time.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int date = 20130406;
        String dateString = Integer.toString(date);
        System.out.println(dateString);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYYMMdd");

        DateTime result = formatter.parseDateTime(dateString);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: You would think so, but all examples I've seen in documentation refer to parsing an existing date time object, rather than having one passed into it.

Answer (score 1):

My approach: convert it to a `String` and then parse the values to convert it into an `int`. You already know the positions of Year, Month, Day, and Hour, so it would be easy.
For example:

```
String dateAsText = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                          .format(new Date(1333125342 * 1000L));


int year= Integer.parseInt(dateAsText.substring(0,4));
```